# How to log data to a database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, database

I am to track who viewed a specific document in a document library, I found out that there is no Item Viewed event or similar event in the SPEventReceiver class. SO I developed a spfx solution that attaches event listeners to html elements. I attached the event listeners on the links to a file I was able to call a function regarding this however I need to log those who viewed the event in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list named logs,
and you can add to it a new item every time a user is viewing your specified document.

Creating a new item you can achieve by javascript REST call:

```
// item = { __metadata: {type: SP.Data.xxxListItem }, ....} 
PostListItem = function (listName, item) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: encodeURI(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items"),
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
    }
});
```

}